# Find the maximum number of valid string combinations given a number

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Given a HashMap where the mapping is:

```
a => 1
b => 2
...
...
z => 26
```

Find the maximum number of strings that could be generated from that number. For example:

```
function("111") = 3
// aaa - 1,1,1
// ak - 1, 11
// ka - 11, 1

function("26") = 2
// bf - 2, 6
// z - 26

function("101") = 1
// ja - 10, 1
// note that there are no other possibilities since 0 does not map to anything
```

It would be helpful if someone could provide the solution code in Java. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: leading zeros are not valid "101"--> 1,01 = (a,a) ?

Comment: what about "901" please clarify

Comment: What this from homework or job interview?

Comment: yeah aa would not be valid for 101, only ja - 10, 1

Comment: for 901, there are no valid combinations

Answer (score 2):

I had this question in some interview, when I did answer the question using pseudo code or just drawing it on the board, the interviewer was very impressed.

**SOLUTION:** 
The idea is to have all the possible combinations that you can make of by the String length which is the function parameter.
Let's say that your input is "111" so the possible combinations are:

- 1,1,1
- 11, 1
- 1, 11

Each time we need to take **one** or **two** places from the String parameter right?
It sounds like binary, so we can mark:

- **one** as '0'
- **two** as '1'

So our combinations above are like:

1. 1,1,1   ==>> 0,0,0
2. 11, 1   ==>> 1,0
3. 1, 11   ==>> 0,1

By each binary combination we can take values from the string and find the letters we need from the ABC. If some value can't be found in range of 1-26 so it's not valid.

The solution starts from a calculation how to find the possible combinations by the String length as given as a parameter.

Comment: just out of curiosity is this solution not exponential in length of string ?

Comment: I don't think so, the String parameter has a final length

Comment: sorry not exponential but still say for one bit string only one possibility for two bit 2, for 3 and above possible(n)=possible(n-1)+possible(n-2) a series like fibonacci which increases quickly thus for large n counting all possibilities while enumerating them would take time if I am not wrong.

Comment: Here n is length of input string

Comment: I don't really know, but the issue here is to see how you solve this kind of algorithm

Comment: yeah, anyways a nice idea to see them as different binary representation +1 to that